# How can change the value of a variable in React Component

Tags: reactjs

I have this React component.I would like to change the value of the variable **title** in the function test() .

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ValueStore } from '../../host/redux/list.store';
import { removeLast } from '../../host/redux/list.action';
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Model } from '../../model';

interface ReactChildComponentViewProps {
   title: String;
   store: ValueStore;
   injector: Injector;
}

var ReactChildComponent = React.createClass<ReactChildComponentViewProps, any>({

    getInitialState: function() {

        console.log( 'Using Angular 2 injector in React body, model.uuid: ' + model.uuid );

    },

    render: function() {
        var title = "Ttile";

        return(
           <div>
               {title}

           </div>
        );
    }
});

export class ReactChildComponentView {

    static initialize(title, store: ValueStore, containerId: string, injector: Injector) {
        ReactDOM.render(<ReactChildComponent title={title} store={store} injector={injector}/>, document.getElementById(containerId));
    }
    static test() {
        console.log('Test');

        //this.props.store.dispatch( removeLast() );
    }
}
```

Is it possible to change the value of title in function test().Is yes How can I do this?

Comment: I am not able to relate to this code. Why do we have angular/core. I have never seen templated createClass before. I thought createClass was deprecated. But even in the good old days, I have not seen code like this. My machine learning brain fails to recognise this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to make `title` dynamic ?
You need to put `title` to the state, then you can easly manipulate it with `this.setState({title:"whatever"});` and in order to display it you need to write `this.state.title`